# consolidate items in a list c#

Tags: c#

I now have two list box, lstStock and lstSupply. lstSupply consists of

```
-Pen
-Pencil
-Staple
-Stapler
-Folder
-Notebook
-Eraser
-Marker
```

and i have two button, one button named btnAdd and another btnRemove.

when i click on btnAdd i want the selected item in lstSupply to be added into lstStock which i have done by

```
    lstStock.Item.Add(lstSupply.SelectedItem);
```

if i select the same item in lstSupply twice, I want it to be consolidated in lstStock.
for instance, if i select Pen twice, the list box shall give me "Pen x 2" instead of Pen in a line and another Pen in another line. 
I got the feeling this is dealing with foreach but i dont really know how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so first of all, you're going to need to store something else in `lstStock.`  I'd suggest something like this:

```
public class StockItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I'd suggest that you don't use the `.Items` field as the actual container where you're storing your stock items. Instead, I'd have a `List<StockItem>` that you use to populate `lstSupply` when you refresh.

```
private List<StockItem> _items = new List<StockItem>();
```

Then, when you click "add", you do two things:

1. Iterate through `_items` to see if there is already a stock item in there of the matching supply. Create one, and add it, if it does not exist.
2. Find the matching stock item in `_items` and increment its `Count`.

To get it to display the way you'd like, we can override `ToString()` in our `StockItem` class.:

```
public class StockItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        if (Count > 1)
            return Name + " x" + Count;
        return Name;
    } 
}
```

Finally, whenever any changes are made, you simply re-populate `lstStock`:

```
private void RefreshGui() {
    lstStock.Items.Clear();
    lstStock.Items.AddRange(_items.ToArray());
}
```

There are plenty of other ways of going about this, but for this simple exercise, this is how I think I would do it.

Comment: Do i need to add some codes in the get and set? Because the lstStock is blank after i click the Add button

Comment: `public int Count { get; set; }` is an [Auto-Implemented Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) - you don't need any code, it adds an invisible backing-field.  You'll need to set `Name` when you create a the StockItem. You can do it like this: `new StockItem() { Name = "somename" };`

Comment: So where do i insert the line new StockItem() { Name = "somename" };? i am new and just learning

Comment: Now i have figured that out and the lstStock is displaying the items selected but it is still not consolidating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to work without extra coding, you could simply do this:

```
if (lstSupply.SelectedIndex > -1 && !lstStock.Items.Contains(lstSupply.SelectedItem))
        lstStock.Items.Add(lstSupply.SelectedItem);
```

this way you are sure that you don't add null items and add each item once max.

Comment: But i want the items can be added several times

Comment: oh right! I did not get that from your question. Anyway I think above solution is right for you.